# Firefox: is there a way to fast switch between Flash-debug and regular Flash?

Tags: firefox, osx-snow-leopard, flash-player

Is there a way to quickly switch between debug-enabled and non-debug versions of Flash player for Firefox?

It seems that I need to reinstall each version if I want to switch.

I am working under Mac OS X 10.6.3 (Snow Leopard).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [portable edition of Firefox](http://www.freesmug.org/portableapps/firefox) and install debug-enabled version of Flash player, while, installing the non-debug edition on the regular install.

Comment: how exactly can i do that ? do i need to copy the flash extension manually to the portable firefox?